# Trying to implement gulp-git and gulp-prompt to allow custom commit messages

Tags: javascript, git, gulp

I'm getting a number of errors when attempting to implement gulp-git with gulp-prompt. I'm trying to give the user the ability to enter their own unique git commit message when the type the command gulp commit. The message should be displayed after the user types the gulp-commit command.

Here is the gulp command

```
//git commit task with gulp prompt
gulp.task('commit', function(){
    var message;
    gulp.src('./*', {buffer:false})
    .pipe(prompt.prompt({
        type: 'input',
        name: 'commit',
        message: 'Please enter commit message...'
    },  function(res){
        message = res.commit;
    }))
    .pipe(git.commit(message));
});
```

Currently I am getting the following errors after I type the command into the terminal..

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
  at Object.module.exports [as commit] (/Users/me/Desktop/Example 4/node_modules/gulp-git/lib/commit.js:15:18)
  at Gulp.gulp.task.gulp.src.pipe.git.add.args (/Users/me/Desktop/Example 4/gulpfile.js:190:15)
  at module.exports (/Users/me/Desktop/Example 4/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
  at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/me/Desktop/Example 4/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
  at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/me/Desktop/Example 4/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
  at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/me/Desktop/Example 4/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
  at startup (node.js:119:16)
  at node.js:929:3

[?] Please enter commit message...
```

Comment: Looks like your running this inside a non-repo? `git init` your repo first.

Comment: I have already ran the git init command, I think it might have something to do with the gulp.src('./*', {buffer:false}) line. should the source be pointed at specific file. The gulp file where I am calling gulp commit is located in the root directory of the folder along with the other files I want to commit. Thanks for your help though @naeramarth7

Comment: strange - exact same error stack when trying this in an not initialised folder - can you reproduce this in an repo and upload it on github for example?

Comment: Do you want me to upload this on Github and send you a link? Sorry I don't understand the question. Yeah this error has been bugging me for hours now

Comment: Exactly - set up a repo on github for us to reproduce this error. It works flawlessly for me: [naeramarth7/so-29568957](https://github.com/naeramarth7/so-29568957)

Comment: The task in question is on line 190 within the gulpfile!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74971/discussion-between-lollipopwizardkid-and-naeramarth7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gulp-prompt does not work well with streams, so gulp-git (here: `git.commit`) will be executed while `message` is still `undefined`. Therefore the gulp-git block needs to be moved inside gulp-prompt's callback:

```
// git commit task with gulp prompt
gulp.task('commit', function(){
    // just source anything here - we just wan't to call the prompt for now
    gulp.src('package.json')
    .pipe(prompt.prompt({
        type: 'input',
        name: 'commit',
        message: 'Please enter commit message...'
    },  function(res){
      // now add all files that should be committed
      // but make sure to exclude the .gitignored ones, since gulp-git tries to commit them, too
      return gulp.src([ '!node_modules/', './*' ], {buffer:false})
      .pipe(git.commit(res.commit));
    }));
});
```